# pytest skips test because it depends on another test

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

In my python unit tests, `test_B` depends on `test_A`. However, when I run the tests with pytest, it always SKIPS test_B with this message:

```
SKIP [1] /home/shuklas/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_dependency.py:88: test_B depends on test_A
```

What am i missing?

```
@pytest.mark.dependency()
def test_A():
    ....

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['test_A'])
def test_B():
    ....
```

Comment: what is the contents of `test_A()`? Does it pass?

Comment: @hoefling no it does not pass. In fact, it successfully completes.

Comment: What version of `pytest-dependency` do you have? Do you have other plugins installed (especially `pytest-xdist`)? You can check this by running `pip list --format=freeze | grep pytest`.

Comment: @hoefling here is the output from that command: pytest==3.4.2, pytest-cov==2.5.1, pytest-dependency==0.3.2

Comment: Then you have to share the test code because I can't reproduce the issue using this package setup and the code you've provided.

Answer (score -1):

Please can you try `@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['A'])` and see if it works?
Thanks